# what could be an acceptable way to add a fix to an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have a question regarding calculating the space used by a table, indexes, etc.
Someone just used the scripts they got from the beautiful answer to that question, and noticed it did not work for sql server 2008 and [posted a way to work around it as an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216453/22336).

It is definitely not an answer, but it might be helpful.

what is the proper way to do this? (show the fix - which is not an answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can improve an existing post while respecting the original author's intent, you should make (or propose) that change [via an edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/editing). As question author, you have a little extra "moral authority", in my view.

More generally, if the answer is [genuinely *Not An Answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag), but could be made so with an edit, consider doing that as well. The best action in each case is highly context-dependent.

If your edit is rejected or rolled back, you also have the option of asking and answering a separate question to preserve the useful content.

In this case, I think the new contribution is a good contribution to the accepted answer, so I have made an edit to incorporate it. The post owner may choose to improve, accept, or reject my edit as usual.

I also left a comment for the author of the improvement, before deleting their answer:

[image: comment]